# Jenkins Pipeline - can't use ConfigSlurper because ConfigObject is not serializable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use groovy ConfigSlurper to load an external config file that's related to a build. I can load the file, but if I try to access it in a pipeline stage, Jenkins dies with a "java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.ConfigObject", but util.ConfigObject is serializable? What gives?

Is there another way to access config files in a way that can return objects so I can access config items like: buildConfig.scm.someUser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use json format as config

[readJSON](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) step to read it

and if you have this cfg.json file

```
{
  "scm":{
    "someUser":"myUser"
  }
}
```

then this code will be valid:

```
def buildConfig = readJSON file: 'cfg.json'
def user = buildConfig.scm.someUser
assert user == "myUser"
```

or you can use yaml format and [readYaml step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readyaml-code-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) with yaml file like this:

```
---
scm:
  someUser: myUser
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great - any idea why ConfigSlurper won't work?

Comment: because in jenkins-pipeline between steps you can use only serializable objects. if you need to use configslurper try to create a function that converts the result of parsing into usual hashmap-arraylist sequence.those objects are serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use ConfigSlurper - the way it is implemented in Groovy means it will cause a serious memory leak in Pipeline.  Unfortunately it's not well-documented (something I need to address today), but this is [noted in the source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/bbf99da6739b37bbaaba21993f4b8a3604224969/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecutionMemoryTest.java#L88) and gets mentioned regularly in tips.

Instead, prefer the [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md) - readYaml, readProperties, readJson, etc -- these are safe constructs and will probably perform a bit better too.